# Why I cannot make an insert to Python list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, insert

I'm trying to insert some item by index to existing list like this:

```
c = ['545646', 'text_item', '151561'].insert(1, '555')
print(c)
```

And I'm getting None in result.

[image: output]

Why I cannot make an insert to the Python list?

The needed output is:

```
['545646', '555', 'text_item', '151561']
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By Python convention, all *mutating* functions return `None`. *Nonmutating* functions return the new value. `insert` is a mutating function (changes the object it operates on), so it returns `None`; you then assign it to `c`.

In fact, there is no way to do this in one statement in current Python. In the future (almost certainly in Python 3.8), there is a proposal for a [walrus operator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/) that will allow you to shorten this:

```
(c := ['545646', 'text_item', '151561']).insert(1, '555')
```

though I believe Pythonistas will frown on it :)

EDIT: With the question in the comments, how to do an insert as an expression? The easiest way is to define another function; for example:

```
def insert_and_return_list(lst, pos, val):
    lst.insert(pos, val)
    return lst

c = insert_and_return_list(['545646', 'text_item', '151561'], 1, '555')
```

You could also avoid `insert` altogether, and use slices and splats:

```
[*lst[:1], '555', *lst[2:]]
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
c = ['545646', 'text_item', '151561']
c.insert(1, '555')
print(c)
```

**Explanation:**

Every python `function` call will return some value or None. In case of `list.insert()` function call, the return value is `None` which you are saving as variable `c` which will be `None`.

**Edit:**
for follow up question in comment:  I'm doing list comprehension and I'm processing the list of the lists. So, every time I would like to change an item in the list using 2 methods insert and pop one by one. How to make these changes while list comprehension?

You should generally avoid `list comp` for it's side effect.

instead do:

```
for sublist in l:
    sublist.insert(1, '555') # or call sublist.pop
```

Comment: Now that you have understood why you are getting value `None` for variable `c`, you can ask followup question in a new question. It will be difficult to change this answer to accommodate what you have not asked and just commented. Just ask another question.

Answer (score 1):

Insert method always returns null .You are trying to print the null type.
Therefore do not map insert method to any variable.Use insert as a method and print the original list
Try this

```
c=['545646', 'text_item', '151561']
c.insert(1,55)
print(c)
```