# How to generate a Python dictionary with simultaneous converting certain strings to floats?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, insert, dictionary-comprehension

Let's say I have `list` of `lists` in `matrix` variable:

```
matrix = [['first', '1,1', 'last'], ['strng_1', '12231,71', 'st_2']]
```

As you can see, all nested lists are having float data written as string. I would like to convert them to `float` datatype.
I need to create a dictionary and make this conversion simultaneously.
For that reason, I've tried to make it using `dictionary comprehension`. So, these operations as one-liner might look like this:

```
dict_comp = {r[0]: r.insert(1, float(r[1].replace(',', '.'))).pop(2) for r in matrix if r}
```

But it doesn't work as expected. And now, after my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57218770/why-i-cannot-make-an-insert-to-python-list) I know why exactly.
Finally, I would like to ask about how to generate a dictionary with simultaneous converting certain strings to floats?

> UPDATE

**Expecting output:**

```
{'first': ['first', 1.1, 'last'], 'strng_1': ['strng_1', 12231.71, 'st_2']}
```

Comment: post the expected result

Comment: you cant save `r.insert(1, float(r[1].replace(',', '.'))).pop(2)` as dictionary value. It will be like `None.pop(2)` which will give you error.

Comment: RomanPerekhrest my question has been updated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following will work:

```
dict_comp = {r[0]: [r[0], float(str(r[1]).replace(',','.')), r[2]] for r in matrix if r}

# {'first': ['first', 1.1, '1,1'], 'strng_1': ['strng_1', 12231.71, 'st_2']}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your `locale` to something that would understand comma as a decimal point, for example `fr_FR.utf8`, use `locale.atof` to convert the string to float, and then revert back your locale

```
import locale 
loc = locale.getlocale() 
locale.setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, 'fr_FR.utf8')

d = {a:[a, locale.atof(b), c] for a,b,c in matrix}

locale.setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, loc)

print (d)
```

**Output**

```
{'first': ['first', 1.1, 'last'], 'strng_1': ['strng_1', 12231.71, 'st_2']}
```

Answer (score 1):

Per my answer [last time](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57218819/240443):

```
matrix = [['first', '1,1', 'last'], ['strng_1', '12231,71', 'st_2']]
[[r[0], float(r[1].replace(',', '.')), r[2]] for r in matrix]
# => [['first', 1.1, 'last'], ['strng_1', 12231.71, 'st_2']]
```

EDIT: If you want to make a dict...

```
{r[0]: [r[0], float(r[1].replace(',', '.')), r[2]] for r in matrix}
# => {'first': ['first', 1.1, 'last'], 'strng_1': ['strng_1', 12231.71, 'st_2']}
```

Answer (score 1):

you cant save `r.insert(1, float(r[1].replace(',', '.'))).pop(2)` as dictionary value. It will be like `None.pop(2)` which will give you error

As per your edited expected output answer by @Carsten should work.

Answer (score 1):

Using dictionary list comprehension

**Ex.**

```
matrix = [['first', '1,1', 'last'], ['strng_1', '12231,71', 'st_2']]
new_list = {x[0]: [(float(i.replace(",",".")) if "," in i else i)for i in x ] for x in matrix}
print(new_list)
```

**O/P:**

```
{'first': ['first', 1.1, 'last'], 'strng_1': ['strng_1', 12231.71, 'st_2']}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the position of the float string is always the same, you can use destructuring assignement in the dict comprehension:

```
>>> matrix = [['first', '1,1', 'last'], ['strng_1', '12231,71', 'st_2']]
>>> {k: [k, float(f.replace(",", ".")), *l] for k, f, *l in matrix}
{'first': ['first', 1.1, 'last'], 'strng_1': ['strng_1', 12231.71, 'st_2']}
```

If the float may be at any position except the first:

```
>>> def try_to_cast(v):
...    try:
...        return float(v.replace(",", "."))
...    except ValueError:
...        return v
...
>>> {k: [k, *[try_to_cast(v) for v in l]] for k, *l in matrix}
{'first': ['first', 1.1, 'last'], 'strng_1': ['strng_1', 12231.71, 'st_2']}
```

See @Sunitha's answer for a cleaner method to convert strings to float using `locale`.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it as constructing a new list instead of changing and existing one.

Assuming this is what you want to do using a dictionary comprehension:

```
dict_ = {}
for row in matrix:
    new_row = row[:1] + [float(row[1].replace(',', '.'))] + row[2:]
    dict[row[0]] = new_row
```

This would then be transformed into:

```
dict_ = {r[0]: r[:1] + [float(r[1].replace(',', '.'))] + r[2:] for r in matrix if r}
```

Generally, though, I would advise against such complicated dict comprehensions. It may be shorter but it is less readable.

Comment: You can not concatenate `list` with `float`

Comment: oops - forgot some brackets